# Light speed and red shift

Tags: photons, speed-of-light, redshift

D. Giovanni et al. showed that the speed of photons through space can be variable if certain structure is imposed on the photons themselves (see their [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.3987) submission or their published work in [Science](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/347/6224/857)). They "imposed structure" on individual photons using a "mask" and successfully measured a difference of photon speed through space as a result.

Has anyone shown that this phenomenon is not the cause of the red shift observed in light from very distant objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper shows that the group speed of a light beam is lower then c. This is due to the fact that the path of the light is effectively longer than for a plane wave. The frequency of the light is constant so this phenomenon can not explain cosmological redshift.